# Change value if it isn't undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm converting an input field to reqular text with this snippet.

```
$(".supernappula").live('click', function() {
   $('.item-quantity .simpleCart_input').replaceWith(function(){
   return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>'
   })    
});
```

However, if the value has already been changed from input to span, it will convert it to `undefined` and it shouldn't do it.

I was thinking a solution like this:

```
$(".supernappula").live('click', function() {
    var howmany = $('.item-quantity .simpleCart_input').html();
    if(howmany == "undefined"){return false;}
        $('.item-quantity .simpleCart_input').replaceWith(function(){
        return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>'
        });
});
```

But it doesn't actually do anything. So basically, how would I stop it from executing if it's already converted?

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but please stop using `.live()`. It's been deprecated for ages now. Use `.on()` (jQuery 1.7+) or `.delegate()` instead.

Comment: Here, it is asked before:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript

Comment: @JamesAllardice seems like people are giving me deprecated solutions then. What are the differences of .on() and .delegate()?

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen - They are just more effective methods for handling event delegation than `.live()` was. Have a look through the jQuery API docs for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encase your replace with a if condition

```
$(".supernappula").live('click', function() {
   if( $('.item-quantity .simpleCart_input').length){
      $('.item-quantity .simpleCart_input').replaceWith(function(){
         return '<span class='+this.className+'>'+this.value+'</span>'
      }) 
    }   
});
```

**EDIT**

Both the class names are assigned to the same input .. You are using the wrong selector..

Try this  `$('.item-quantity.simpleCart_input')`

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qXv6Z/1/)

What `$('.item-quantity .simpleCart_input')` means is that .simpleCart_input is a child of `.item-quantity` which is wrong in your case ..

Both classes are associated to the same element .. So your selector should not have any spaces between them..

Comment: Thanks, it works, though I created a workaround and moved the snippet to my ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You element must have at least a white space inside.
So you can do the verification with something like this:

`if($.trim($(".item-quantity .simpleCart_input").html()) == ""){return false;}
...`